# How to optimize this c program to find the prime factorisation of a number

Tags: c++, primes, prime-factoring

I have written a code for prime factorization of a number but I don't know how to optimize it to get better result for larger digits can anyone have idea about that?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int prime(int p, int q, int r);
int main(){
int n,c=0;
scanf("%d",&n);
for(int j=2;j<=n;j++){
    int t=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=j;i++){
        if(j%i==0){
                t++;
    }
 }
 if(t==2){ //check whether J is prime or not
    //  printf(" %d ",j);
        c=prime(n,j,0); //check whether j has any factors with N 
        if(c!=0){
            printf(" %d ",j);
            printf(" %d \n",c);
    }
 }
 }
 return 0;
}
int prime(int p,int q,int r){
    if(p%q==0){
        r++;
        prime(p/q,q,r);
    }
    else{
    return r;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first thing I permit to suggest you is to explain a bit your code by commenting it and by "beautifing" it a little. 
Second, can you please explain what do you mean with "get better results for larger digits"?

Comment: better result means reducing the execution time and regarding the code what i did is i took every number less than N to which we have to find the factorization, and check whether it is prime or not and if it is prime then check whether it has factors with the given number and this loop continues till the last number N

Comment: I can suggest you to read something about the whole theme: Polland-Strassen factorization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm and a question in math.stackexchange: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631559/algorithms-for-finding-the-prime-factorization-of-an-integer

Comment: Since your code is split in two functions, I suggest you to start by optimizing the prime function. You can read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test and

Comment: Thanks @francesco-b actually my main query is how to optimize a code and as this is my own code so optimization of this code may gives me much  clarity about that so i have posted this question

Answer (score 1):

Your code is equivalent to

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(int j=2; j <= n; j++) {     // for each j in 2..n,

        int t=0;
        for(int i=1; i<=j; i++) {   // count j's divisors
            if(j%i==0) {            //   among 1..j
                t++;
            }
        }

        if( t==2 ){                 // if j is prime:   NB!
            int c=0, nn=n;
            while( nn%j==0 ) {      //   count multiplicity of j 
                c++;                //   as divisor of n, and
                nn /= j;
            }
            if( c!=0 ){             //   report a prime divisor and 
                printf(" %d  %d \n", j, c);   // its multiplicity
            }
        }
     }
     return 0;
}
```

but actually all that is needed is this:

```
int main(){
    int n, c=0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(int j=2; j <= n; j++) {     // for each j in 2..n,

            int c=0;
            while( n%j==0 ) {       // if j divides n
                c++;                //   count its multiplicity
                n /= j;             //   while dividing it out of n
            }                       //   NB!  changing the `n`  NB!
                                    //   which guarantees j is prime
            if( c!=0 ){             //       when c != 0
                printf(" %d  %d \n", j, c);
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and so the final significant optimization is

```
int main(){
    int n, c=0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(int j=2; j*j <= n; j++) {   // here

            int c=0;
            while( n%j==0 ) {
                c++;
                n /= j;             
            }
            if(c!=0){
                printf(" %d  %d \n", j, c);
            }
    }
    if(n>1) {                       // and here
        printf(" %d  %d \n", n, 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Next you can try to find a way to increment `j` by *2* in the main loop, to range over just odd numbers, because no even number above *2* can be prime.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
//function to check for prime numbers (return '1' if prime ,else return '0').
int checkprime(int pr)
{
    if ((pr==2)||(pr==3))
    {
        return (1);
    }    
    else
    {
        for (int  i = 3; i <pr; i=i+2)
        {
            if (pr%i==0)
            {
                return (0);
            }
            
        }
        return 1;
        
    }
    
}
//function to print the prime factors.. 
int primefactors(int num)
{
    int temp;
    temp=num;
    while(temp!=0 && temp%2==0)
    {
        if (temp%2==0)
        {
            printf("2 ");
            temp/=2;
        }
        
    }
    for (int k =3; k <=temp&& temp!=0 ; k=k+2)
    {
        if (checkprime(k)==1)
        {
            while ((temp!=0) && (temp%k==0))
            {
                printf("%d ",k);
                temp/=k;
            }
    
        }
        
    }
}
int main()
{
    int a;
    a=65;
    if (a>1)
    {
        primefactors(a);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("variable 'a' should be greater 1!");
    }
    
    
    

    
}
```